# Use JavaScript to change the nature of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html form that has a select menu.  The last option on the menu is 'other'.  What I would like to do is if the user selects 'other' the select menu turns into a text field.  I know this can be done with show/hide feature of jQuery, but I am trying to keep it simple.  I have feeling this is not really possible, but is there a JavaScript command (jQuery or not) that will turn the select element into an input element?

Comment: no there is not.... as you said you can have a hidden input field which will become visible when other is selected... also I would recommend keeping the select as visible so that the use can change the selected value if he want

Comment: What if someone chooses `other` by mistake?

Comment: Yeah, agreed with @Musa that it would be best to have a way to change your choice.

Comment: Show/hide is your easiest option.  Just put all possible types of elements in the page and then show/hide the ones you want at any given point in time.  Very simple and used quite commonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HYkdr/))

```
<select id='choices' name='Choice'>
    <option>Ford</option>
    <option>Toyota</option>
    <option>Honda</option>
    <option>Other</option>    
</select>
```

With this JavaScript

```
$('#choices').on('change', function() {
    var choice = $(this);
    if(choice.val()=== 'Other') {
        choice.replaceWith('<input name="Choice"/>')
    }
});
```

Or for a more robust solution ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HYkdr/4/))

```
<div class='ChoiceWithOther'>
    <select name='Choice'>
        <option>Ford</option>
        <option>Toyota</option>
        <option>Honda</option>
        <option>Other</option>    
    </select>
    <input name='Choice' disabled='disabled'/><a href='#' class='UndoChoice'>&times;</a>
</div>
```

With this JavaScript:

```
var select = $('select[name=Choice]'),
    input = $('input[name=Choice]'),
    undo = $('.UndoChoice');

select.on('change', function() {
    if(select.val()=== 'Other') {
        select.prop('disabled', true); //Disbaled inptus won't be sent on FORM submits
        select.hide(); //Don't confuse user

        input.prop('disabled', false);
        input.show();
        undo.show();
    }
});

undo.on('click', function() {
    select.prop('disabled', false); //Disabled inputs won't be sent on FORM submits
    select.show(); //Don't confuse user
    select.val($('option:first', select).val()); //reset to first value

    input.prop('disabled', true);
    input.hide();
    undo.hide();
});

input.hide();
undo.hide();
```

Comment: And if you want to change back…?

Comment: That's kind of the weakness of the OP's request, but I can cook up an alternative... one sec

Comment: I can do it for you, one second.

Comment: I think I would need to disable the `<select>` input, though.

Comment: I think I prefer your HTML/JavaScript over mine. I just covered more edge cases

Comment: Very nice!  Clean, simple solution.  I would have ton win circles forever and ended up with tones of extraneous code.  To answer the question, I was not planning of giving the option to go back to the select menu, but since it is provided, I will probably use it.

Comment: Luxelin, you should post your answer. I'll vote it up :)

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript solution: [**JSFiddle Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/C6dUF/3/)

Replaces the select element with a text field. Comment out `document.getElementById("choice").remove();` and uncomment the else statement if you want to keep the select element, so that the end user can change their choice.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="choice" onchange="checkOptions(this.value);">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function checkOptions(value) {
    form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    if(value == "other") {
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("id", "otherText");
        form.appendChild(input);
        document.getElementById("choice").remove();
    }
    /*else {
        if(document.contains(document.getElementById("otherText")))
            document.getElementById("otherText").remove();
    }*/
}
```